# Javascript to Disable checkboxes in a table with variable rows

Tags: javascript

I have a table which can have variable # of rows. how can I disable all checkboxes at once?

```
   <table border="1"  class="myTable grid">
    <tr align="center">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1;1" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2;1" value="1" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
     </table>
```

Comment: If you could use jQuery, `$('.myTable input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')` would do the trick.

Comment: @JohnBupit perfect!! Thank you!

Comment: Please mark your question as solved.

Comment: @pyb how do I mark it solved? Thanks!

Comment: @Kaur there should be a button or tick on the left of each answer. You can only pick one.

Comment: Disabled checkboxes values are never sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript only solution that disables *all* checkboxes in myTable.

```
document.getElementByClassName("myTable").querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']").disabled = true;
```

Comment: It's `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery solution would be:

```
$('.myTable input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Alternatively:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myTable input[type=checkbox]').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing a `for` loop to iterate `NodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll(selectors)` , set each `[type=checkbox]` element to `disabled` within `for` statement

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="myTable grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb1;1" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb2;1" value="1" checked>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have more checkboxes on the form with type checkbox; hence I am targeting these only with table. Thanks for your input.@guest271314